# Line inside editor

Tags: netbeans

I am trying to remove this line from my Netbeans editor view. I have no clue what it's for, and I find it disturbing.

How can I remove it? (Can't find it in color settings)

Here's a picture:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the right margin setting to 0.

[image]